# Forward and Back Buttons react where the Caret Position is

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

Playing with the idea of a Keypad-Login.
I need to make Forward and Back Buttons.
The back and forward buttons seem to be getting the caret position.
The input is disabled and only button clicks are used.
How can I adjust the buttons A and B to not just type at the end of the value but place the letter where the caret position is?

```js
function A(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "A"; }
function B(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "B"; }
function BackSpace(){document.getElementById('user').value=document.getElementById('user').value.substring(0,document.getElementById('user').value.length - 1);}
  
function Back(){
user.focus();
console.log(user.selectionStart-1);
if(user.selectionStart > 0 ){user.focus();
user.selectionEnd = user.selectionStart-1;
user.selectionStart = user.selectionStart;}}

function Forward(){
console.log(user.selectionStart);
user.focus();
user.selectionEnd = user.selectionStart+1;
user.selectionStart = user.selectionStart+1;}
```

```html
<div>
<button type="button" id="userKeysIn">
<span class="">Username</span>
<input id="user" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="user">
</button>
</div> 
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="A();">a</button>
<button type="button" onclick="B();">b</button>
<button type="button" onclick="BackSpace();">Backspace</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Back();">Back</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Forward();">Forward</button>
</div>
```

No JQuery Please.
And Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` to check caret position

Here is something you are looking for

```
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};
function writeValue(value) {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('user');
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('user').value;

  if (userInput.selectionStart === userInput.selectionEnd) {
    inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, userInput.selectionStart) + value + inputValue.substring(userInput.selectionStart, inputValue.length);
  } else {
    inputValue = inputValue.replaceBetween(userInput.selectionStart, userInput.selectionEnd, value);
  }
  document.getElementById('user').value = inputValue;
}

function A(){ 
  writeValue("A");
}
function B(){
  writeValue("B");
}
```

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/Koxogr?editors=1011)

Comment: this doesn't work on ie how can i make that possible

Comment: Which IE version did you test?

Comment: I used version  IE 11.0

Comment: If you put `<input>` outside the `<button>`. That will work :)

Comment: Please let me know If it work. I like to hear your feedback

Comment: Ill see if i can work around that.  The reason for the button around the input is to run some Ajax to bring up the keypad. Thanks